# NextJS getting error on the first npm run dev ./src/app/globals.css.webpack[javascript/auto]!=!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/css-load

Tags: next.js, frontend, tailwind-css, next.js13, npm-start

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EjBM.png) error code

I created a new next-js project (next js 13 ) by `npx create-next-app@latest`
What is your project named? my-app

Would you like to use TypeScript? No / Yes

Would you like to use ESLint? No / Yes

Would you like to use Tailwind CSS? No / Yes

Would you like to use `src/` directory? No / Yes

Would you like to use App Router? (recommended) No / Yes

Would you like to customize the default import alias? No / Yes

What import alias would you like configured? @/*
I use **YES** in all the above questions

My tailwind.config.ts look like this

```
import type { Config } from 'tailwindcss'

const config: Config = {
  content: [
    './src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './src/app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        'gradient-radial': 'radial-gradient(var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
        'gradient-conic':
          'conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
export default config
```

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "20.4.10",
    "@types/react": "18.2.20",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.7",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
    "eslint": "8.47.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.13",
    "next": "13.4.13",
    "postcss": "8.4.27",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.3",
    "typescript": "5.1.6"
  }
}
```

when I run npm run to start it should run default next js page on localhost:3000